# Как посмотреть размер раздела на диске?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Допустим у меня есть диск sda. Мне нужно посмотреть занимаемый размер на sda6.

Есть команда df -h, но она показывает всю информацию по дискам, а  мне нужен только раздел sda6 на диске sda.

Comment: df -h /dev/sda6

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

если раздел примонтирован, то можно посмотреть его размер, указав путь к нему:

```
$ df /dev/sda6
```

если же раздел не примонтирован, программа *df* бессильна, и можно посмотреть лишь информацию о всех разделах данного блочного устройства. пара вариантов:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print all
```